# Sample code for Saas AWS Marketplace Integration in .net core or React js

Tags: aws-marketplace

I want to integrate my .net core 3.1 react js app to AWS Marketplace,
But not sure how to call ResolveCustomer and BatchMetering service API from my app.

if any have done this Please share a sample code for my above app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the serverless sample and call it from your application: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-marketplace-serverless-saas-integration